# Access 2003 SQL: Syntax Error in from clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I'm trying to combine two tables with join in Access 2003, however I keep getting:

> Syntax Error in from clause.

I don't understand what's wrong, Google didn't help me either...

```
INSERT INTO Korrekturentlastung_Kurs
SELECT * 
FROM 
(Korrekturentlastung_Lehrer_Schueler 
INNER JOIN Korrekturentlastung_aktuelle_Schueler)
```

Comment: You are missing an `ON` clause.

Comment: There's no `ON`

Comment: Post sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `ON` clause.

If you want all combinations from the two tables, you can use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Korrekturentlastung_Lehrer_Schueler INNER JOIN
     Korrekturentlastung_aktuelle_Schueler
     ON 1=1;
```

This is equivalent to a `CROSS JOIN` in other databases -- which Access does not support.  Or, you can use a comma:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Korrekturentlastung_Lehrer_Schueler,
     Korrekturentlastung_aktuelle_Schueler;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
However, I keep getting the error "Duplicate output destination 'SchuelerID'" when I execute this:
INSERT INTO Korrekturentlastung_Kurs
SELECT * 
FROM 
(Korrekturentlastung_Lehrer_Schueler 
INNER JOIN Korrekturentlastung_aktuelle_Schueler
ON Korrekturentlastung_Lehrer_Schueler.SchuelerID=Korrekturentlastung_aktuelle_Schueler.SchuelerID )

Comment: @Fabulierer . . . You should select the columns that you actually want and not use `SELECT *`.